# Accessing Firefox tab element in nsIWebProgressListener::OnStateChange using C++

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing extension for Firefox 3.0-3.5 versions using VS2008.

I want to set attribute to a tab once the document load request completes within that tab window.

So in OnStateChange method, I am checking for document load.
I have used STATE_STOP & STATE_IS_DOCUMENT for it.

I want to determine which tab window has been associated with particular document request.

I have valid DOM Document pointer got from nsIWebProgress *aWebProgress which is 1st input
parameter of OnStateChange.

```
if ((aStateFlags & STATE_STOP) && (aStateFlags & STATE_IS_DOCUMENT))
{
    nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindow> domwin;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMDocument> domDoc;
    aWebProgress->GetDOMWindow(getter_AddRefs(domwin));
    domwin->GetDocument(getter_AddRefs(domDoc));
}
```

I have tried to get nsIDOMDocumentXBL pointer by QIing nsIDOMDocument pointer(domDoc in my example) but it fails with Error code 0x80004002 (2147500034) i.e.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE.

How do I get the tab element corresponding to document load request.

Could any one please help me?

Thanks in Advance,
Vaibhav D. Gade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understood the question correctly and you want a  for a content window, you probably need https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Accessing_the_elements_of_the_top-level_document_from_a_child_window to get the chrome window, then run the implementation of gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument in the chrome window.

You'd save yourself a lot of time if you stopped writing C++ and switched to JS for such things.

Comment: Definitely going JS is the way here. You'll save a lot of headaches.